# Custom code UI desgin Or Framework like Bootstrap, Foundation etc

Tags: html, css, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been assigned a task of redesigning existing project screens with latest technology in responsive web design (RWD) to support more devices.

I have analysed there are frameworks like bootstrap, foundation which support RWD. Initially, I thought to use them, but when I discussed with UI design team they advised me not to use framework for styling and pointed below reasoning.

**Framework advantages (bootstrap, foundation etc,.):**

1. Support will be high
2. Easy to learn
3. Code will be maintainable
4. Built in support for RWD

**Disadvantages**:

- Framework is not good for all kind of UI design.
- Bootstrap is basically considered based on the type of layout and controls used in the UI. The current UI doesn’t leverage much of Bootstrap’s framework.
- This is very difficult to customizing the bootstrap to suite you requirement. Suppose if we use bootstrap then we may end up customizing majority of the built in styles and functionality. That is equal to writing code without framework. Moreover, if plain CSS3, HTML and JQuery is used then the pages will be light weight compare to framework with custom styling and functionality.
- Writing custom styles over the Bootstrap framework involves lot of effort, hence it’s not recommend, unless and otherwise the layout is simple and adoptable.
- Due to the tailor made UI, we are bound to override most of the Bootstrap classes, which is not beneficial.

Please throw some lights on what is good. Also what is your take on Custom Code Vs Framework in Design perspective. If you have more points to add to advantage and disadvantages please do so as well.

Comment: Foundation is much easier to customize, especially if you disable $include-html-classes.

Comment: @methyl, if I start customizing foundation framework then i will end up with more of custom  code. This is equal to using CSS3 and HTML without foundation. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I just had the same discussion in my head a couple of weeks ago. I came to a conclusion that if I need a very quick nice-looking design, for a school project or something, I don't really want to put a lot of effort in, I'll use a framework. Otherwise, for _my own projects_, CSS from scratch. Takes a bit more work, but I have **full** control of the design, and I can change stuff easily.